# Unity and Vuforia project lost, how i edit an apk?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have a big problem with Unity. A week ago, I made an Android app, augmented reality. I compiled the application in APK format. After a week of making this application in unity and vuforia, during this time my hard drive broke down.

My question is, how can I modify an apk already created .. because I only have the project created. All I have is the apk that's left on the phone.

Is there any possibility?

I looked for results .. but in vain. Thank you !

Comment: Hm unfortunately I doubt it. You can't decompile an APK into a Unity project or something like that .. than you would be able to decompile any APK and copy the code behind it...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's possible to get some data from the apk such as scripts you wrote.
It depends on how did you compile your apk.
If you used IL2CPP I would say it's lost, but if you used mono as a scripting backed you can try decompiling it. (Not if you used code obfuscating etc.)

To do so you will need apktool and program like dnspy. (Maybe also aapt)
Than you should use apktool to get dlls. Here is a sample apktool.bat that will use apktool.jar to get dlls.

```
@echo off
if "%PATH_BASE%" == "" set PATH_BASE=%PATH%
set PATH=%CD%;%PATH_BASE%;
chcp 65001 2>nul >nul
java -jar -Duser.language=en -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 "%~dp0\apktool.jar" %*
```

After running command

> apktool d appname.apk

You should navigate to appname\assets\bin\Data\Managed.

In this folder you will find Assembly-CSharp.dll and Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll.

You can open dlls using dnSpy and get most of your code.

However the process can be complicated if you are doing it for the first time, so take your time. If you have any further questions I can try to explain how to do it.

The other things you can do: (to get your scripts/maybe even assets back)

You can try using some of the unity editor extensions like Unity Unpacker. Most of them are paid and usually does not work very well.

In the future I recommend using some sort of version control. It makes life easier and you don't have to worry about backups. Also if you need to get back to something you had a few days ago it's just a few clicks. For that you can use Unity Teams, Github for Unity or stuff like that.